# What would a Bayushi Samurai think of the Scorpion Shinobi if he realizes those exist?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, l5r

It's a common knowledge that Samurai despise ninjas, consequence of their lack of honor, counter-posed with the Bushido lifestyle.

But what if you are a Samurai from the trickiest families, and the Ninja is from your own clan?

I could not find any record that punctuates this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I'm going to clarify two terms for the purpose of this answer.

**Ninja** is a subtype like "warrior".  The techniques they employ may not have anything to do with a clan or any higher purpose.

**Shinobi** is a term almost exclusively used for the Shosuro Infiltrator in the L5R universe.  They serve exactly one person: their own personal lord as part of the clan even if not directly acknowledged.

Shosuro Infiltrators are everywhere.  They are sometimes deep undercover agents in disguise as opposed to a shadowy figure skulking in black pajamas (but they'll do that too).  They can be information gatherers, assassins, or simply well-placed resources if their lord wants to be up to something.  But that's the main catch: They serve *only* their personal lord.  Whatever clandestine tasks they are given, they must carry them out and trust that their lord has a greater plan in mind.  They don't have to follow any tenet of bushido to get the job done except for this caveat of Loyalty.  Most Scorpion samurai are aware that there are agents in the field and **whether or not the shinobi in question is in alignment or against their plans will determine the reaction of even their clansmen.**

A ninja they have the right to kill outright (although may easily be disinclined to do so) as being part of a lower social caste or try to use as a double agent since there is a strong chance they are simply a mercenary to begin with.

Comment: So a Samurai does not care how the clansmen life paths affects the vision other families could have of the clan, as long as they do it "for the clan"?

Comment: They care, and in fact families within a clan, or even the same family will sometimes be at odds if their goals don't sync.